# [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript

***Hi guys! I'm starting with programming one week ago and so, I've tried to do a function to check. 
 but it is not working.***  What should I do to fix it?

```js
function verificar() {
//probably the error is her, but can't see what is it.
  
var radio = window.document.querySelector('input#espirito1')
var radio = window.document.querySelector('input#espirito2')
var radio = window.document.querySelector('input#espirito3')

var res = window.document.querySelector('div#res')


    res.innerHTML = `Voce è a sailor moon ${res}`
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-Br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>which sailorMoon are you?</header>
    <section>
<div>
    
    <p> Estado de espirito:// idk if the error is here.
        <input type= "radio"  name="espirito1" id="espirito1">
        <label for="serena">happy</label value=1>
        <input type="radio" name="espirito2" id="espirito2">
         <label for="Rei">Confident</label value=2>
        <input type="radio" name="espirito3" id="espirito3">
        <label for="Mina">sweet</label value=3> 
    </p>
<input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="verificar()">
</div>
<div Id = "res">
click to know which sailormoon are you.
</div>

    </section>
    <script src="estilo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to do a test like Buzzfeed, but im totally lost!

Comment: Hola! This is hard to understand... What do you expect to happen? And what is the problem? Maybe this link is a good start on your way to clarify you question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: That is confused. You want to insert the selected radio value in the "#res" div? You are inserting the "#res" object inside the "#res" html (inception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess that's what you want to have... if not, please elaborate on the question

```js
function verificar() {
  //probably the error is her, but can't see what is it.

  var radioEspirito1 = window.document.querySelector('input#espirito1');
  var radioEspirito2 = window.document.querySelector('input#espirito2');
  var radioEspirito3 = window.document.querySelector('input#espirito3');
  var res = document.getElementById('res');

  let name = "";

  if (radioEspirito1.checked) {
    name = radioEspirito1.value;
  } else if (radioEspirito2.checked) {
    name = radioEspirito2.value;
  } else if (radioEspirito3.checked) {
    name = radioEspirito3.value;
  }



  res.innerHTML = `Voce è a sailor moon ${name}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-Br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>Qual sailorMoon voce è?</header>
  <section>
    <div>

      <p> Estado de espirito:// idk if the error is here.
        <input type="radio" name="espirito1" id="espirito1" value="Serena">
        <label for="espirito1">feliz</label>
        <input type="radio" name="espirito2" id="espirito2" value="Rei">
        <label for="espirito2">Confiante</label >
        <input type="radio" name="espirito3" id="espirito3" value="Mina">
        <label for="espirito3">Delicada</label > 
    </p>
<input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="verificar()">
</div>
<div id="res">
Preencha os dados para saber qual deusa voce èe, gatinha!
</div>

    </section>
    <script src="estilo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya! perfect, was it! Thanks so much! now i can see where I've made my mistake!

Comment: You're welcome :) Please consider accepting the answer, if it helped you ;)